# "a person who's disseminated "

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

As it came in the sentence:

> Internally focused and at the same time **disseminated**, they’re inclined to unexpected contrasts of behavior where shyness and apathy are replaced by emotional elevation, determination and activity, a melancholic look - or inspired/joyful.

What does it mean for a person to be disseminated?

resource:
http://www.the16types.info/vbulletin/content.php/14-Type-and-subtype-descriptions-Meged-Ovcharov

Comment: Can you specify what you're looking for?

Comment: I couldn't really guess what does it mean to say that a person is "disseminated"..

Comment: @Hiba22 And your question is?

Comment: The above passage would not seem to me to have been written by a native speaker.

Comment: What does a "disseminated person" mean?

Comment: It was writtin originally by russians

Comment: OED says of adjectival **disseminated** *spec. of a disease: dispersed or spread throughout an organ, a tissue, or the whole body*. I doubt the (prolly nns) writer intended that - I reckon he meant *diffuse[d]* (i.e. - ***not** focused*).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a non-standard usage by a non-native speaker

Comment: @FumbleFingers But its an interesting possibility - as an antonym to *focused*. *Disseminated* is how I have often felt on a Monday morning about 7.00am.

Comment: @WS2: *If* I were to feel anything on a Monday morning about 7.00am (unlikely, since I'd normally be fast asleep) it would be somewhere between *withered* and [*slightly foxed*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Slightly-Foxed-desirable-Searles-Collecting/dp/028562945X). But I agree with A.P. that what we have here is just a bad translation, not really a matter of English usage at all.

Comment: To me, the interesting thing about this question was that it reminded me of the relationship between *to scatter* and *scatterbrained*. In Russian it would *be disseminate* and "disseminated" (*absent-minded*, that is.)

Comment: I think that the author opposed the "focused" and "disseminated" states, where disseminated is used for "**dissipated**" or "inattentive" as a child in a classroom (i.e. thinking to various things not related to the main subject).

Comment: I find that this usage is an example of a "malapropism" which is a valid english language construct, regardless of its origin.  this question should not be closed.

Comment: It is impossible to tell what the author intended.  "Scaterbrained" (the most literal translation of "disseminated") doesn't seem to fit the person being described, but neither does simply having a broad range of interests fit.

Answer (score 2):

The intended meaning here is **absent-minded**. The word provides contrast to "focused", as you can see in context:

> Internally focused and at the same time disseminated

This is just a poor translation.

([Russian source](http://www.socionics.org/forums/storage/4/528540/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8.htm))

The confusion comes from the fact that the Russian verb *rasseivat* (рассеивать) could be translated *to scatter* or *to disseminate*. But a "rasseyanny" person (рассеянный, same root) should be *absent-minded* or *forgetful*.

The translator went with *disseminated* instead.

**There's a similar relationship between *to scatter* and *scatterbrain* in English as well.**

---

Edit: I understand not everyone can read Russian, but for what it's worth here's a screenshot from Google's built-in service. I've highlighted the relevant parts:

[image]

The screenshot demonstrates that *disseminated* and *absent-minded* can both be legitimate translations of the same Russian word *рассеянный* (rasseyanny).

Comment: I don't think any word/phrase in the context indicates the word provids contrast to "focused".

Comment: "At the same time" should be "but at the same time". "The person is focused, but at the same time X" -- that's what I meant by contrast.

Comment: You should not attempt to read the author/translator or whatever 's mind. There's got to be reason why the word was chosen by him and we never know. You are merely speculating for a soon-to-be closed off-topic question.

Comment: I'm not speculating, I can read Russian very well, and I looked up the source. This is a textbook example of a translator's error. That's the reason.

Comment: You just proved the question is off-topic.

Comment: Perhaps. But at least the OP got the correct answer.

Comment: @Rathony Incidentally, why is it offtopic? What rules does it violate?

Comment: I belive you already visited [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions). Translation and non-English languages are off-topic.

Comment: @Rathony Thanks, but the link you provided just gives me the newest questions...

Comment: [Sorry](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: I think bad translations *are* Off Topic, so the question should be closed. But this seems to be unquestionably the correct answer, and it would be too long to fit into a comment, so it doesn't seem unreasonable to post it as an answer. Anyway, I've upvoted the answer because I think it's *right*, and if I could I'd upvote it again purely for the point about *scatterbrained*. I'm tempted to think it's the same basic figurative sense as *wooly-minded*, contrasting with *sharp-witted, concentration, letting one's mind wander*, etc. (all in one place/spread out **|** focused/vague).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have been repeatedly told by members not to answer off-topic questions. I don't think it is a matter of the correct answer. Double standards should not be applied. Russian source and the translation have nothing to do with the question and the answer is also off-topic as it is not a Russian-English translation site.

Comment: @Rathony: We're not in a court of law here. Besides which, by the time you read this the question probably *will* have been closed. But as implied above, I think there *is* a potential On Topic (for ELL if not ELU) issue here, re figurative usages relating to mental capacity and efficient use thereof that may be so "standard" for Anglophones that we don't necessarily even register them as metaphoric, but which may seem opaque or "random" to nns. Also, imho "Russian source and the translation" are practically *everything* to do with the question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Nobody could verify whether the answer is correct or not unless he/she knows Russian better than the translator of the original sentence. Are you sure disseminated means what A.P claims to be right? I have no idea. You have to ask Russian & English bilingual to confirm it, which cannot be done here unfortunately. That's why it is off-topic here. The guideline clearly states so, too.

Comment: @Rathony: Well, I know what *disseminated* means and how it's used (incl. the "disease" sense), so by implication there *must* be some reason why it's used inappropriately in the cited example. And I've no reason to suppose the writer *isn't* Russian, that A.P. can't read Russian perfectly well, or that his/her link isn't to the original "Russian source". Without going into details, I think there are many indications that the writer isn't a native Anglophone - but he's reasonably competent, so I assume he's using *X and at the same time Y* "correctly" (with the implication *Y = **NOT** X*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, exactly. Therefore, it is off-topic to base the answer on the Russian knwoledge and translation and assert that the translation is poor. Nobody knows. Still I have not downvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

This usage falls into the english language usage category of a "malapropism."  In this instance it does seem to have occurred due to a translation issue, but malapropisms are often used for humor as well.

The word "malapropism" originates from the stage play "Arsenic and Old Lace", in which a character, Mrs. Malaprop, used words that were incorrect but close enough in sound to be recognizable for what word was intended, to great comedic effect.

After 2001, these are also referred to as "Bushisms" due to the alarming frequency of their occurrence in President Bush's spoken language.